# Django модели интернет-магазина

Tags: django, model, интернет-магазин, eav, content-type

Ломаю голову над задачей, но понимаю, что не могу решить сам.

**Описание проблемы:**

Допустим есть некий интернет-магазин со следующими моделями: 'Category', 'Subcategory', 'Basis', 'Property', 'Product'.

Как можно заметить в модели Basis добавлена связь с моделью property - M2M, так мы получаем нужные характеристики для группы продуктов, вместо того, чтобы выбирать характеристики для продукта по отдельности.

**Вопрос**:

На данный момент мы имеем Basis который группе продуктов присваивает одни и те же характеристики* - модель Property. Но если выбирать значения* (поле  data модели Property) в модели Property, то значения соответственно дублируются собственно как и сами характеристики для каждого товара.

(*небольшой пример в терминологии: Характеристики- "ширина": Значения - "100";)

*Как присвоить значения для характеристик?* Чтобы каждый Product находящийся в своем Basis имел одинаковые характеристики, которые в свою очередь имели разные значения относительно продукта.

**Кратко о методах которыми пытался реализовать**:

Пробовал использовать [Django EAV](https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav), фреймворк  [Contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), [JsonField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield).

Перелопатил много вопросов в гугле, касающихся реализации характеристик, конкретики не нашел. Пересмотрел множество вопросов касающихся данных методов. Из этого всего самое толковое, что нашел [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895429/how-exactly-do-django-content-types-work), и то мне не помогло. Все равно не понимаю как в своей задаче это реализовать.

Уверен, что решение кроется в правильной реализации этих методов, но я не смог точно ни с одним разобраться. Подозреваю, что Data должна быть отдельной моделью, но не приходит в голову как ее связать с Product и все тут.

Если так и есть подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно и толково будет это сделать, у меня уже мозг замылился и к решению прийти не могу долго. Спасибо.

```
#models/product.py

class Category(models.Model):
    """ Category of products """
    name = models.CharField('Название категории', max_length=250)
    alias = models.CharField('Алиас', max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    icon_field = models.ImageField('Изображение', blank=True, null=True, upload_to='category_icon/')
    ...


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    """ Subcategory of products """
    name = models.CharField('Название подкатегории', max_length=250)
    alias = models.CharField('Алиас', max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Категория', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    icon_field = models.ImageField('Изображение', blank=True, null=True, upload_to='subcategory_icon/')
   ...
  


class Property(models.Model):
    """ Properties of products, tec-info """
    name = models.CharField('Свойство', max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    alias = models.CharField('Алиас', max_length=200, db_index=True)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Значение')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True)
    ...


class Basis(models.Model):
    """
        Basis (of products which have same tec info and properties, as group of same products in Basis)
        That decision easy to use*, than get property separate to each product. In this decision you can 
        get the list of properties to basis and this list of properties will be displayed in group of 
        products which is includet to Basis object.
        Also this decisions uses to large markets which have big nomenclature, and different association 
        with naming of categories
        *Easy to use - is when you assign some properties to group of products, instead assign properties 
        to every product
    """
    name = models.CharField('Название основы', max_length=250)
    alias = models.CharField('Алиас', max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    subcategories = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, verbose_name='', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    properties = models.ManyToManyField(Property, verbose_name='Свойство', related_name='property')
    icon_field = models.ImageField('Изображение', blank=True, null=True, upload_to='basis_icon/')
    ...


class Product(models.Model):
    """ Products in catalogue """
    name = models.CharField('Название продукта', max_length=250, db_index=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(
        Brand,
        verbose_name='Бренд',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='brands'
    )
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        Collection,
        verbose_name='Коллекция',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='collections'
    )
    article = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=250, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField('Описание')
    price = models.DecimalField('Цена', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField('Наличие товара', default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Дата и время создания товара', auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField('Дата и время последнего изменения', auto_now_add=True)
    title_img = models.ImageField('Изображение', upload_to='products/')
    categories = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        verbose_name='Категория',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='categorys'
    )
    subcategories = models.ForeignKey(
        Subcategory,
        verbose_name='Подкатегория',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='subcategorys'
    )
    basis = models.ForeignKey(
        Basis,
        verbose_name='Основа',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='basises'
    )
    ...
```

В коде все лишнее, не относящееся к вопросу поудолял, чтобы не отвлекало от вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сделать классическую [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) модель (плюс мелкие добавления типа категорий, которые существенно не влияют на проблему, с которой вы столкнулись).

Проблема у вас возникла, потому, что вы не разделили `Attribute` и `Value`. Они у вас сейчас представлены в одной таблице `Property`. И идея, что `Data должна быть отдельной моделью` - это оно и есть, а именно выделение `Value` в отдельную джанго модель.

[image: EAV model]

Для наглядности я переименовал джанго модели.

`ProductType` - это аналог `Basis`. Он описывает тип продукта, т.е. по сути какие у продукта данного типа могут быть характеристики. Собственно список возможных характеристик - это `PropertyType` (описывает тип характеристики и к какому `ProductType` она пренадлежит).

Для каждого типа продукта можно создать конкретные экземпляры. Они хранятся как `ProductInstance` (у вас это `Product`). У каждого экземпляра продукта есть конкретные значения характеристик. Они хранятся как `PropertyInstance` (возможно `PropertyValue` или `ProductInstancePropertyValue` будет более подходящим или понятным названием). Ну и каждый `PropertyInstance` содержит собственно значение характеристик конкретного продукта и ссылку на `PropertyType`, который описывает тип хранящегося значения.

Пример

```
ProductType (тип продукта)
--+------
id|name
--+------------
1 | мобильный телефон
2 | ноутбук

ProductInstance (конкретный продукт)
--+-----------------+-----------------
id| product_type_id |name
--+-----------------+---------------
1 |               1 | iphone 10
2 |               1 | samsung galaxy S5
3 |               2 | macbook pro 15
4 |               2 | dell xps 13

PropertyType (тип характеристики)
--+-----------------+-------------------------+------
id| product_type_id |name                     | type
--+-----------------+-------------------------+------
1 |               1 | операционная система    | string
2 |               1 | поддержка bluetooth     | boolean
3 |               2 | диагональ экрана        | integer
4 |               2 | вес                     | decimal


PropertyInstance (значение характеристики конкретного продукта)
--+---------------------+-------------------+------
id| product_instance_id |  property_type_id | value
--+---------------------+-------------------+------
1 |                   1 |             1     | IOS 13   
2 |                   1 |             2     | true
3 |                   2 |             1     | Android 7   
4 |                   2 |             2     | true
5 |                   3 |             3     | 15   
6 |                   3 |             4     | 2.5
7 |                   4 |             3     | 13
8 |                   4 |             4     | 1.6
```

Я к названиям добавил `Type` и `Instance` чтобы в четче разделить где тип, а где экземпляр, в этом объяснении.
А вообще, возможно, `ProductType`, `Product`, `Property` и `Value` окажутся более практичными названиями.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, за подробное объяснение. Надеялся не изобретать велосипед, на том и напоролся.